# Algorithm Libraries for using OpenMP with C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, thrust

I use the C++ programming language with GCC on a GNU/Linux desktop. I am trying to implement
some PRAM parallel algorithms in C++. As I understand, with  OpenMP on a multicore CPU more or less, helps to emulate CREW PRAM algorithms.

Many sophisticated PRAM algorithms,  involve operations like parallel-prefix sum, sorting, 
performing an element wise operation on a vector in global address space etc.

Somehow, after about 15 mins of Googling,  there seem to be no libraries which provide this functionality, i.e. some out of the box basic parallel algorithms or data structures like the Standard Template Library.

Can anyone list any such libraries?

EDIT: What I  need, essentially,  is an OpenMP analogue to the Thrust Library which is used in
the CUDA world. http://thrust.github.com/

Comment: openmp is barebones.  intel tbb perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrust supports parallel execution on multicores through OpenMP or TBB as well as GPUs through CUDA. From the [website](http://thrust.github.com/):

> Thrust is a parallel algorithms library which resembles the C++
>   Standard Template Library (STL). Thrust's high-level interface greatly
>   enhances programmer productivity while enabling performance
>   portability between GPUs and multicore CPUs. Interoperability with
>   established technologies (such as CUDA, TBB, and OpenMP) facilitates
>   integration with existing software. Develop high-performance
>   applications rapidly with Thrust!

Here's some additional [information](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends) on how to access Thrust's multicore functionality.

Comment: Oh this looks great! Are all of the Thrust algorithms/functions which work on the GPU supported for the multicore case?

Comment: @smilingbuddha: Yes, all algorithms are supported.